# SQL Script to run on a daily basis and upload results into a folder on an FTP Server

Tags: sql-server, ftp, automation

I am using SQL Server and I need to write a script that will run a very simple query against the database and output the results as an Excel file or CSV file. It should then upload the result of that query to a specific folder on an FTP Server.

After some research on the web, I came across articles that are getting me more confused that shedding some light on the task in hand.

My query looks like follows:

```
USE MyDatabase
SELECT * 
FROM Reservation
```

Assuming that the login details (username/password) on my SQL Server database is user15/12345 and the login details on the ftp server is ah/5478, how do I turn the SQL Query above into an automated SQL script that will run on a scheduled time (say, 04.00am) everyday?

Comment: SSIS.................

Comment: @MitchWheat And SQL Server Jobs.

Comment: @MitchWheat Thanks. I will look into that direction and see if I can come up with a solution!